# Windows 10 - vagrant plugin install vagrant-aws - The "libxml2" package isn't available. (RuntimeError)

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows-10, vagrant

Trying to install aws plugin for vagrant. Getting a dependency error.

Logs show...

```
find_executable: checking for xml2-config... -------------------- no

--------------------

"pkg-config --exists libxml2"
package configuration for libxml2 is not found
```

Console output:

```
C:\Users\jkittell\Documents\Schedule3> vagrant plugin install vagrant-aws
Installing the 'vagrant-aws' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Bundler, the underlying system Vagrant uses to install plugins,
reported an error. The error is shown below. These errors are usually
caused by misconfigured plugin installations or transient network
issues. The error from Bundler is:

ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Users/jkittell/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.4/gems/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.2.4/ext/ovirtsdk4c
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20181002-19764-xj4q7a.rb extconf.rb
checking for xml2-config... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-libxml2-config
        --without-libxml2-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
extconf.rb:29:in `<main>': The "libxml2" package isn't available. (RuntimeError)

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  C:/Users/jkittell/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.4/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.4.0/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.2.4/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Users/jkittell/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.4/gems/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.2.4 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Users/jkittell/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.4/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.4.0/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.2.4/gem_make.out
PS C:\Users\jkittell\Documents\Schedule3>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a google search and found a [hotfix](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/pull/542) for this.

Gem file available [here](https://github.com/bdwyertech/vagrant-aws/releases/tag/v0.8.0-bdwyertech).
Just do a vagrant plugin install ~/PATH/TO/vagrant-aws-0.8.0.gem

I had to install fog-aws plugin first and then it worked.

`vagrant plugin install fog-aws`

Console output:

```
PS C:\Users\jkittell\Documents\Schedule3> vagrant plugin install ..\..\Downloads\vagrant-aws-0.8.0.gem
Installing the '..\..\Downloads\vagrant-aws-0.8.0.gem' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Fetching: iniparse-1.4.4.gem (100%)
Fetching: fog-core-2.1.2.gem (100%)
Fetching: fog-aws-3.3.0.gem (100%)
Bundler, the underlying system Vagrant uses to install plugins,
reported an error. The error is shown below. These errors are usually
caused by misconfigured plugin installations or transient network
issues. The error from Bundler is:

conflicting dependencies fog-aws (= 2.0.1) and fog-aws (~> 3.0)
  Activated fog-aws-3.3.0
  which does not match conflicting dependency (= 2.0.1)

  Conflicting dependency chains:
    vagrant-aws (= 0.8.0), 0.8.0 activated, depends on
    fog-aws (~> 3.0), 3.3.0 activated

  versus:
    fog-aws (= 2.0.1)

PS C:\Users\jkittell\Documents\Schedule3> vagrant plugin install fog-aws
Installing the 'fog-aws' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Successfully uninstalled dry-inflector-0.1.2
Successfully uninstalled fog-aliyun-0.3.2
Successfully uninstalled fog-atmos-0.1.0
Successfully uninstalled fog-aws-2.0.1
Successfully uninstalled fog-brightbox-0.16.1
Successfully uninstalled fog-cloudatcost-0.1.2
Successfully uninstalled fog-core-1.45.0
Successfully uninstalled fog-digitalocean-0.4.0
Removing console
Removing setup
Successfully uninstalled fog-dnsimple-1.0.0
Successfully uninstalled fog-dynect-0.0.3
Successfully uninstalled fog-ecloud-0.3.0
Successfully uninstalled fog-google-0.1.0
Successfully uninstalled fog-internet-archive-0.0.1
Successfully uninstalled fog-joyent-0.0.1
Successfully uninstalled fog-local-0.6.0
Successfully uninstalled fog-openstack-0.3.6
Successfully uninstalled xml-simple-1.1.5
Installed the plugin 'fog-aws (3.3.0)'!
PS C:\Users\jkittell\Documents\Schedule3> vagrant plugin install ..\..\Downloads\vagrant-aws-0.8.0.gem
Installing the '..\..\Downloads\vagrant-aws-0.8.0.gem' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Installed the plugin 'vagrant-aws (0.8.0)'!
PS C:\Users\jkittell\Documents\Schedule3> vagrant plugin install vagrant-aws
Installing the 'vagrant-aws' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Installed the plugin 'vagrant-aws (0.8.0)'!
PS C:\Users\jkittell\Documents\Schedule3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
vagrant plugin install fog-aws
vagrant plugin update
vagrant plugin install vagrant-aws
```

This should upgrade fog to a version 3.5 or greater